# compare password by using scanf or getch

Tags: c

I wanna make login program.
ID, PW are chosen. User enter their ID, PW and compare,
when I write all password and press 'enter', but it doesn't print 'login success'. I make '         if (password[i] != 13) { ' this to stop while method by push enter. When I push enter key, login program doesn't stop

```
    scanf("%d", &ID);

    printf("password: ______\b\b\b\b\b\b");
    while (1) {
        password[a] = _getch();

        if (password[a] != 13) {
            printf("*");
            a++;
        }
        
    }

} while (userID != ID || int(userPassword) != int(password));

printf("login success");
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a description of an actual problem nor a question.

Comment: 0) `int(password)` is invalid C ... 1) casting a string to `int` does not do what you want it to do; try `atoi(password)` ... or, even better, use `strtol()`

Comment: I put more detail about problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need "something" to stop the `while(1)`loop - perhaps a `break` statement:

```
    if (password[a] != 13) {
        printf("*");
        a++;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
```

Further, you can't compare an integer value (i.e. `int userPassword`) with an array of integers (i.e. `int password[10]`)  using

```
int(userPassword) != int(password)
```

you need some code to calculate an integer value from the values in the array.

Alternatively, you can make `userPassword` an array like:

```
int userPassword[10] = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5};

int password[10] = { 0 };
```

and later use `memcmp` to compare the arrays.

Or perhaps use simple strings

```
int userPassword[10] = "123345";

int password[10] = "";
```

and later use `strcmp` to compare the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

> The _getch and _getwch functions read a single character from the console without echoing the character...

```
password[a] = _getch(); // Gets a char input
```

You are trying to use _getch() to read an integer, this will only give you the value of the integer in the ascii table, for example entering 1 will give you the number 49.

Also you are using an infinite loop while filling the array

```
while (1) {
        password[a] = _getch();

        if (password[a] != 13) {
            printf("*");
            a++;
        }
```

while 1 means while true means forever. so even if you get the right password the computer will never stop waiting for more input and in the end will reach beyond the memory allocated to your array.

You should use the same method you used for the id, which means instead of:

```
while (1) {
    password[a] = _getch();

    if (password[a] != 13) {
        printf("*");
        a++;
    }
    
}
```

just:

```
scanf("%d", &password);
```

in the end you try to cast value which is already an integer and an array to integer
so that means you should just change password to an integer as well

instead of:

```
int password[10];
```

do:

```
int password = 0;
```

also the way of casting in c is not

```
int(something)
```

but

```
(int)somthing
```

so your code should look like:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int userID = 1234567;
    int userPassword = 123345;

    int ID;
    int password = 0;

    do
{
    printf("ID: ________\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b");
    scanf("%d", &ID);

    printf("password: ______\b\b\b\b\b\b");
    scanf("%d", &password);

} while (userID != ID || userPassword != password);

printf("login success");
```